# CSS not compiling (theme.css) on a PrestaShop site on local environment

Tags: css, webpack, compilation, prestashop

I have a custom theme on my PrestaShop website, trying to work on the CSS on a local environment. When I modify the CSS, the compiled file theme.css is not updated.

It is a windows environment, php app, and I am using virtual studio & git bash.

I modified the theme.css and it changed on the site on local. 
I tried to launch webpack for reloading doing "npm run build" but got an error "missing script".

> Do I have to append the webpack config?

---

> How can I have an automatic reload of the minimized files?

Answer (score 1):

By changing the theme.css file you have updated the compiled CSS files which will render during the document load. But after running the command **npm run build** the changes made in theme.css file are removed. As the files get overwrite on a compilation with **npm run build** command.
So if you want the changes to reflect then add the changes in the CSS files present inside a _dev directory. So that on compilation the changes get updated in the theme.css file.

**How can I have an automatic reload of the minimized files?**

You can use **npm start** command to compile the file automatically on updating the files inside _dev directory.

Comment: same problem with this command I get an error "missing script: start"

Comment: Hello Claire,

Please make sure you have added the "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack -w",
    "build": "webpack"
  }
in package.json file and then run the command npm run build or npm watch or npm start

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on PS1.7+ you shouldn't touch the theme.css anyway.
Best way is to create a child theme and have in its assets a custom.css.
Also add all your template changes in this child theme.
This way you can always upgrade the parent theme without loosing the changes.
Or, if you don't want to do this way at least add a custom.css to your current theme and made your css changes there.

Answer (score 0):

You must run `npm run build` in the _dev/ folder of your theme.
Before that, you must run `npm install` in the _dev folder.
Do not use nodejs > 8.
package.json and webpack.config.js of _dev/ folder are quite old. I am working on updating them.